# How could could one connect power bi and algolia?

Tags: powerbi, algolia

How could could one connect power bi and algolia? I did some research, and I've found no examples. Somewhat related, I've seen no mention of how to connect mongodb in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

The PowerBI community takes ideas for new connectors and other features. There is one for MongoDB to which you can add your vote.

https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/7017782-mongodb

It seems that algolia has not yet been suggested as a desired new connector. Maybe you want to go and suggest it. Suggestions with many votes are more likely to be developed than ones with few votes.

Comment: its the most popular noSql and they don't already support it. Sad!

Comment: Yeah, well, there seem to be aspects of the development life cycle that you may not be aware of, like resources, budgets and prioritization. Why do people expect Microsoft to always produce everything for everyone in the first release? And totally free, of course.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good business decision to support integrating with the third most popular data store in the world?

Comment: Probably. That's why they are looking at it.